# Hiding Email Address Form Alter

Tags: emails, users

I'm trying to hide non-admin users to view the email address field in the user section. I have the following hook. Right now, I have the current password hidden, but the email sends back a naughty validation requiring email to be added.

Answer (score 1):

You can use similar code as below to hide pass and mail field with optional value.

```
//drupal_set_message('not admin!');
$form['account']['current_pass']['#required'] = FALSE;  
$form['account']['current_pass']['#access'] = FALSE;
$form['account']['mail']['#required'] = FALSE;    
$form['account']['mail']['#access'] = FALSE;



$form['#validate'] = array_diff($form['#validate'], array('user_validate_current_pass'));
$form['#validate'] = array_diff($form['#validate'], array('user_validate_mail'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to alter Drupal so that it doesn't require email addresses for users, you should look at this module: https://www.drupal.org/project/optional_mail

Read the module description carefully. User emails are deeply integrated into Drupal, and not having them can cause all kinds of unexpected problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Field Permission](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module. It allows you to set permission for every field for every role in your website. So if you prevent non-admin users from accessing this field, they wont see it.